# Vue - Issue with props filled using axios request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-component

I have 3 vue components List, Car, AddNew

**List.vue** is the parent component and have 2 components like this:

```
<add-new :cars-models="carModels"></add-new>                

<car
 v-for="(car, index) in items"              
:key="car.id" 
:data="car" 
:car-models="carModels" 
>                   
</car>
```

later it has this:

```
data(){

   return{
     items:'',
     carModels:''     
  }

}
,
created(){
     axios.get('car-models')
         .then(({data})=>{                              
            this.carModels= data;                           
        }); 

      axios.get('cars')
         .then(({data})=>{                  
            this.items = data;  
         });                    
}
```

In the **addNew.vue** I have this:

```
props: ['carModels'],
data(){
   return {
      models:''
   }
},
watch:{

        carModels(){
            this.models= this.carModels;
        }

    }
```

I had to use the watcher because carModels is filled in the parent component, is it ok here, but, in the **Car.vue**

```
props: ['carModels'],
data(){
   return {
      models:''
   }
},
watch:{

        carModels(){
            this.models= this.carModels;
        }

    }
```

As you can see, it is the same, but **this.models** is not filled with the prop carModels, despite the prop is filled!. I don't know what is happening. 
Thank you

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this is a timing issue. The watcher carModels isnt being triggered because the value for carModels is there since the creation of the component. What you can do is modify the data so it looks like this:

```
 return {
      models:this.carModels
   }
```

this way, the props data is copied at first, then updated by the watcher whenever the props is updated

```
props: ['carModels'],
data(){
   return {
      models:this.carModels
   }
},
watch:{    
        carModels(){
            this.models= this.carModels;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Now it is working, thank you, but I wonder why in the other component everything was ok

Comment: The axios calls are asyncronouse, so they may be completed sometime after the created method was called. In fact, its likely that the created method will finish and the component will get to the mounted method before your data returns. 

This means that your first component will get rendered without data, then it will be feed data when it arrives, so it triggers your watcher

Comment: Your second component is different, since is a for statement, they dont exist unless there is data to iterate over. The watcher is waiting for the parent to modify the value of the prop. It doenst trigger at the creation of the component

So if you get the list of models first, then a second later you get the list of cars. Vue will render the car component with the models props already filled, before the watcher is active, so it will not trigger the watcher.

Thats why in this case you also want to make sure to copy the props to your data.